# How to Add Methods and Equations to a Class

Tags: c#

I am doing a trip console application in C# and can't figure out where to put the methods and equations to make the application run. I need to calculate MPG and Cost per gallon. I am new to programming and am drawing a blank. I attached two pictures of what the beginning console window is supposed to look like and what the result window looks like. If anyone can tell me what direction im supposed to go in I would appreciate it.
 [console beginning user input window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGPa.png)
    [Result Console Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beUgz.png)

**class W8M2A1_CTripAppProgram**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace W8M2A1_TripApp
    {
        class W8M2A1_CTripAppProgram
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Display Welcome Message
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Trip Fuel Cost Calculator- Valentina       Woodson March 4, 2016 (v.1)");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

                //Prompt for destination input
                Console.Write("Enter Trip Destination City: ");
                string yourDes = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                //Prompt for trip mileage
                Console.Write("Enter Rount Trip Mileage: ");
                double roundtMil = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                //Prompt for Gallons used
                Console.Write("Enter Number of Gallons Consumed for the Trip: ");
                double galCon = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                //Prompt for fuel Cost per Gallon
                Console.Write("Enter Fuel Cost Per Gallon: ");
                double fuelpGal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");              

                //Display information
                Console.WriteLine("Your Trip Cost Are Shown in the Following:");
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------\n");

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class Trip:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace W8M2A1_TripApp
    {
        class Trip
        {
            // Declare data items: destination, round trip mileage, gallons consumed, full cost per gallon
            string yourDes;
            private double roundtMil;
            private double galCon;
            private double fuelpGal;
            private double mpg;                  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You (are using) cannot use a concrete class in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

For something this simple you could pretty much complete everything in the single static method. Unless, you were specifically trying to work with methods return values, etc.

Also, when you read the values from the console, you aren't writing the value back to the console.

After you have received all the input, you could perform the calculations and `Console.WriteLine(galCon*roundtMil)` the result after `Console.WriteLine("Your Trip Cost Are Shown in the Following:");`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to Trip class:

```
public void Fill (string yourDes, double roundtMil, double galCon, double fuelpGal)
{
    //fill all those private fields you need for calcuation
}
public void CalcAndPrint ()
{
    //calcuate and print the result to the console
}
```